# Getting ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [OPTIONS] "/users" when trying to POST data to RAils server with AngularJS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, angularjs, ruby-on-rails-4, angular-resource

Having issue when trying to POST data to Rails server from my AngularJS side.

**The server error:**

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [OPTIONS] "/users"):
  actionpack (4.1.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.1.9) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.1.9) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.1.9) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.1.9) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.1.9) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.1.9) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.9) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:26:in `call'
  rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:84:in `call'
  rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
  railties (4.1.9) lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
  railties (4.1.9) lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call'
  rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  thin (1.6.3) lib/thin/connection.rb:86:in `block in pre_process'
  thin (1.6.3) lib/thin/connection.rb:84:in `catch'
  thin (1.6.3) lib/thin/connection.rb:84:in `pre_process'
  thin (1.6.3) lib/thin/connection.rb:53:in `process'
  thin (1.6.3) lib/thin/connection.rb:39:in `receive_data'
  eventmachine (1.0.8) lib/eventmachine.rb:193:in `run_machine'
  eventmachine (1.0.8) lib/eventmachine.rb:193:in `run'
  thin (1.6.3) lib/thin/backends/base.rb:73:in `start'
  thin (1.6.3) lib/thin/server.rb:162:in `start'
  rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:16:in `run'
  rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/server.rb:264:in `start'
  railties (4.1.9) lib/rails/commands/server.rb:69:in `start'
  railties (4.1.9) lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:81:in `block in server'
  railties (4.1.9) lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `tap'
  railties (4.1.9) lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `server'
  railties (4.1.9) lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
  railties (4.1.9) lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
  bin/rails:8:in `require'
  bin/rails:8:in `<top (required)>'
  spring (1.3.6) lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
  spring (1.3.6) lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
  spring (1.3.6) lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
  spring (1.3.6) lib/spring/client.rb:26:in `run'
  spring (1.3.6) bin/spring:48:in `<top (required)>'
  spring (1.3.6) lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
  spring (1.3.6) lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
  bin/spring:13:in `require'
  bin/spring:13:in `<top (required)>'
  bin/rails:3:in `load'
  bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

So here will be my Rails server controllers and routes files.

**User Controller**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def index
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json {render json: { name: 'Jonhy'}, callback: params[:callback]}
    end
  end

  def new

  end

  def create_user
    puts user_params
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      render json: { error: false }, layout: false
    else
      render json: { error: true }, layout: false
    end
  end

  def show

  end

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation)
  end
end
```

**Application Controller**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  before_filter :allow_ajax_request_from_other_domains

 def allow_ajax_request_from_other_domains
   headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = 'http://localhost:8001'
   headers['Access-Control-Request-Method'] = '*'
   headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = '*'
 end
end
```

**Routs**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  root 'home#index'
  resources :users do
    collection { post :create_user , via: :options  }
  end
end
```

And here is my AngularJS where i make the POST Ajax.

```
var App = angular.module('OutOfBox', ['ng.deviceDetector','ngRoute','ngResource']);
App.factory('Users',

  function($resource){
    var users =
     $resource('http://127.0.0.1\\:8001/:user', {user:'users'}, {
        query: {method:'GET', isArray: true},
        save: {method:'POST', isArray: false}
     });
     return users;
  }
);
App.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope','$http','Users', function($scope,$http,Users) {
    $scope.user = [];
    $scope.responsive = [];
    $scope.submit = function() {
      if ($scope.users.email && $scope.users.password && $scope.users.password_confirmation) {
        $scope.user.push(this.users);
         Users.save({user: $scope.user}, function(){
         console.log(':)')
        }, function(error){
          console.log(error)
        });
        $scope.users = '';
      }
    };
}]);

App.config(['$routeProvider','$locationProvider','$httpProvider',
  function($routeProvider, $locationProvider, $httpProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/home', {
        templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl'
      }).
      otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/home'
      });
              // use the HTML5 History API
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
        $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["X-Requested-With"];
  }]);
```

So i tried a lot solutions but no one fixed my.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Rails cannot process `[OPTIONS]` requests

You have to install [rack-cors](https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors) to process CORS.

Here's where your problem comes from:

```
  resources :users do
    collection { post :create_user , via: :options  }
    # via: :options ?

  end
```

Comment: @Trusislv1, also if you serve UI from same domain, protocol and port, you will not need this as the `pre-flight` OPTIONS requests would not be sent at all.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was posted long ago, but I had this issue...

I used `gem'rack-cors'`, but in my case I dealt with this with a different setting.

`config/application.rb`

```
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.middleware.use Rack::Cors do
      allow do
        origins '*'
        resource '*',
                 headers: :any,
                 expose: %w(access-token expiry token-type uid client),
                 methods: %i(post)
      end
    end
  end
```